# "Installing" CoreAudio headers on Mac OSX

Tags: header, installation, core-audio

I've been at this for a few days now and I can safely say I'm stumped and haven't made progress on my own. I'm attempting to compile a project included in the XCode documentation (SinSynth) but every time I attempt to build it, I get errors upon errors about missing header files. "Okay," I thought enthusiastically, "Take a deep breath and let's use this as an opportunity to better learn XCode."

I looked at the paths the compiler told me it was looking for the headers in, added them, and then got more warnings because files needed to reference one another in the same folder (This files were not the missing header files - they were other files included that had definitions and what looked like boiler plate code). At this point I was a bit confused as to why the headers weren't installed in the first place. I uninstalled and reinstalled XCode but still had the same errors.

My question is where do I need to put the header files and cpp files included in the Audio Tools for Mac download? This is my first time having to break open XCode and add content, and thus far I've found no newbie-friendly tutorials to help me with this. To say it bluntly, I'm confused! What should I do?